# Add windows user to a particular database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a windows user who I want to add to just one database `SalesDeals` on the server. I added them in `SalesDeals-> Security -> Users` section of the Database and gave them db_datareader permissions on the database. I cannot add them in the Top level Security section since I don't have permissions for that.

The issue is when the user tries to connect to the server CS01\CS01 they get login failed for the user error.

Do I need to get them added to the top level Server -> Security -> Users section for them to be able to connect to the Database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must first [create a `Login` on the SQL Server instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-2017), then [create a `User` in the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017) which maps to that `Login`.

Without a `Login`, the user cannot be authenticated to SQL Server (unless you're using a Contained Database, which is not a feature of your version of SQL Server), so they won't be able to access the database.

Comment: Oh ok..I was thinking I can directly add the windows user in the security section of the database and they should be able to connect to it..

Comment: My understanding is that this is only possible with Contained Databases, and that's a SQL Server 2016 feature.

Comment: OK Thanks..for SQL Login I know we had to create it on the server instance but I thought windows user could directly be added to the database security

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Windows User as a Contained Database User in SQL Server 2012 ([see here](http://zarez.net/?p=2760)) using the steps you've performed, but that login failure will occur if you're not specifying the database in your connection string, or in SSMS if connecting via SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

How access works in SQL Server unless the database is a contained database. :

Login-->user-->role

So to provide access, you need a login created which will allow access to the instance and then map this login with the required database. This will create the user and permissions (role) can be granted.

[Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017)